# How can I use awk to separate a two column file delimited by an equal sign?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

The real problem I have is that my file looks like this:

```
username=password
```

I know I can use -F=, however what can I do if the second column which may contain an equal sign?

```
name=laskjf9w8u23;oi4==
```

Currently the code I have is chopping off the last equal sign.  And I can only assume that if there was an equal sign earlier in that string that it would also get chopped.

Here is what I have currently:

```
cat file.txt | grep "=" | sed 's/\//\\\//g' | awk --field-separator "=" --assign file="<outfile>" '{printf "\"s/@%s@/", $1 ; for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) { printf "%s", $i ; if ($i != $NF) printf "=" } ;  printf "/g\" %s\n", file; }' | xargs -n2 sed -i
```

Cheers!

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Try to indicate what is your final goal here. You have cat, sed, grep and awk in the same line, which can be probably handed by one awk.

Comment: The entire story is that I am using this to do token replacements, and the final out come will be a new file that is used for authentication.

The first file that I cat has the delimited data, then I am replacing lines in the second file where the field is "@NAME@" and matches a field in the first file.  Hence the long combination of sed and awk commands.

Comment: Sorry, hit return too quickly.  I want to avoid truncating the las column as there are only two columns and this will not change.  So if awk finds "==" to ignore it.

Does that help a bit more?

Comment: I suspect you already know that a series of grep+sed+awk commands is completely unnecessary and you could do it all in just one awk command. If you post a new question with some sample input (contents of file.txt) and desired final output from the whole pipeline we can help you.

Answer (score 5):

Do you really have to use `awk`? The easiest way to do such separation is `cut`:

```
echo "name=laskjf9w8u23;oi4==" | cut -d= -f2-
laskjf9w8u23;oi4==
```

Note the `-f2-`. It means grabbing 2nd to last group, so you won't end up with just `laskjf9w8u23;oi4`. It will handle the latter equal signs as well.

`-d=` sets `=` as a separator.

Answer (score 2):

Through sed,

```
$ echo 'name=laskjf9w8u23;oi4==' | sed 's/^[^=]*=//'
laskjf9w8u23;oi4==
```

`^` matches the start of a line and `[^=]*` negated character class which matches any character but not of `=` , zero or more times. Replacing the matched characters with an empty string will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

@IgorHatarist has the right solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28630815/1745001) if you want to just print the text after the first `=` sign, but just for completeness and in case you need to do more than that:

```
$ echo "name=laskjf9w8u23;oi4==" |
awk '{f1=f2=$0; sub(/=.*/,"",f1); sub(/[^=]+=/,"",f2); print "<" f1 ">:<" f2 ">"}'
<name>:<laskjf9w8u23;oi4==>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using grep as

```
$ echo "name=laskjf9w8u23;oi4==" | grep -oP '=\K.*'
laskjf9w8u23;oi4==
```

OR

using sed as

```
$ echo "name=laskjf9w8u23;oi4==" | sed -r 's/[^=]*=//'
laskjf9w8u23;oi4==
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use `cut` for this simple problem, but if you really want to use `awk` (perhaps because the real problem is more complicated and requires `awk`), here's how:

```
awk '{print substr($0,index($0,"=")+1)}'
```

This will print the contents of each input line following the first `=`, or the entire line if it does not contain an `=`. (That works because `index` returns `0` if the search string is not found, so in that case the substring starts at `0+1`, and in `awk` string indices start at 1.)

If you wanted to print nothing in the case that there is no `=`, then you could use this:

```
awk '/=/{print substr($0,index($0,"=")+1)}'
```

Or, if you wanted to ensure that the line contained a valid identifier followed by an `=`, something like this:

```
awk '/^[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*=/{print substr($0,index($0,"=")+1)}'
```